# When to use const before function and when you shouldn't

Tags: c++

I can't figure this out. I'm trying to recreate "complex" c++ class and those functions.

For example: `real(), imag(), abs()` etc. use parameters as `const complex& obj`. So I thought if you pass object by its reference it is not copied and saves a bit of memory and is faster and use `const` in front of it to avoid messing up that object. Am I right?
So I thought I could create my functions like those as well, but why those functions that have parameter with `const` need to be `const` functions them selves?
Here is what I got:

```
class MyComplex{
private:
    double real;
    double imag;
public:
    MyComplex();
    MyComplex(int real);
    MyComplex(int real, int imag);
    double getReal();
    double getImag();
    void setReal(int real);
    void setImag(int imag);

    friend const double real(const MyComplex& obj);
    friend const double imag(const MyComplex& obj);
    friend const double abs(const MyComplex& obj);
    friend const double arg(const MyComplex& obj);
    friend const double norm(const MyComplex& obj);
    friend const std::string conj(const MyComplex& obj);
    friend std::string myPolar(double rho, double theta);


};
```

If I don't put const in front of them they don't work.

```
const double real(const MyComplex& obj){
    return obj.real;
}
```

Other functions are very similar.

Comment: it basically means that you are returning const double, so you cant write to it(unless you copy from the value, afaik)

Comment: By the way, those functions are not `const`-qualified, the return value is. For the function to be `const`-qualified it would be declared as `... double real( ... ) const;` with the `const` at the end.

Comment: @clcto: ...which isn't even a valid signature for a non-member function.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley true ...

Comment: Avoid returning const T from a function, it is useless. (Note: not talking about const T&, which is returning an internal reference)

Comment: What do you mean by "they don't work"?

Comment: "If I dont put const in front of them they don't work" - in front of *what* ? Your friended function has no problem returning `obj.real`. It isn't modifying anything. Or did you mean `obj.getReal()` does *not* work? if so, that would be because `obj` is const, and thus you cannot invoke a non-const member function (i.e. `double getReal() const { return real; }` would be appropriate).

Comment: Well they work, but if I try to call objects functions it doesnt allow it.

Comment: You know `friend`-functions are not syntactically functions of the class, even though they are semantically part of them?

Comment: I know that they can access private part of object. Whats your point?

Comment: Btw: Your freestanding (friend) functions (besides the functions returning a string) are a nice design - just drop that const after friend.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Are they? More like, they should be implemented in terms of the public interface.

Comment: Thats what I did, made getImag() and getReal() const member functions and made them unfriendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration

```
friend const double real(const MyComplex& obj);
```

does not declare a const function, it declares a non-const function that returns a constant value. Since you return by value anyway, this `const` is plain useless.

A const function is declared like this:

```
//within the class definition
double getReal() const;
```

This makes the implicit parameter to `getReal()`, the `this` pointer, `const`, allowing you to do `myConstComplex.getReal()`.

And, as Deduplicator correctly notes, just kick those friends, you don't need them and you don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is bad.

What you should change:

`getReal` and `getImag` should be `const`-member-functions (Add the qualifier after the parameter-list).

All those `friend`-functions should not be so friendly, implement them just with the public interface.
(Remember that encapsulation means minimizing the amount of code depending on the classes internal details.)

Anyway, there is seldom a reason to have a `const`-qualified return-type. I never had one.
Making the return-type `const` might even sometimes break things.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to return const built-in type or object.